# GitHub create repository button clickikng in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, github, automation

I am making a python program that creates a git and GitHub repository and makes the first commit but I am not able to click the create repository button I have tried every way to click it I have the full code it is in a GitHub repository(link https://github.com/Shuvadip-Ghosh/Git-and-GitHub-automator the line to click button is in 33 and 47.

and Thanks in advance

Comment: In case you are open to a different solution, the github api may be of interest to you https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api#repositories

Comment: I would prefer the approach given by Dillion as this would be so much quicker than Selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to click on Create repository which is in the end of the page, then you will have to scroll down all the way till end, and then using `//button[contains(text(),'Creat')]` this xpath with explicit waits, you should be able to click on it.

**Code : -**

```
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Creat')]"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```